# Out of RAM Memory on Msp430

Tags: c, static, msp430

I ran out of RAM on my MSP430 because I am getting this message;

```
Error[e16]: Segment DATA16_Z (size: 0x638 align: 0x1) is too long for segment definition. At least 0x44 more bytes needed. The problem occurred while  
processing the segment placement command "-Z(DATA)DATA16_I,DATA16_Z,DATA16_N=0200-_SYS_RAM_END", where at the moment of placement  
the available memory ranges were "CODE:20b-7ff" 
   Reserved ranges relevant to this placement: 
   200-7ff              DATA16_I 
Error while running Linker
```

So I found that the problem is due to these static variables within one of my functions;

```
  static float circularBufferTemp[CIRC_BUFF_WIDTH_SCH3] = {0};
  static float circularBufferHumi[CIRC_BUFF_WIDTH_SCH3] = {0};
  static UCHAR indexMeasTemp = 0;
  static UCHAR indexMeasHumi = 0;
```

Now the question is; How can I avoid this problem considering that I have to save those variables inside that function every time it is called by my application code?

Comment: That is not the only memory that adds up to your problem. You might look at other variables ending up in that region. For these specific variables, you might reduce the size to reduce memory usage.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I need decimal point.

Comment: @SupportUkraine thank you very much it is a good idea. I could try to implement it. The only problem is that it will cost a lot of changes to my code because every time I use that data I will have to do a division step, if I understood correct

Comment: @SupportUkraine I tried using char instead of float to gain more memory space. Curiously, the compiler now says "At least 0x84 bytes more is needed", when before it was only 0x44 bytes. I still don't understand how much memory I have to save.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider:

- Compress your data. As your data are sensor data you might consider, for instance, to save deltas instead of full values.
- Reduce buffer and increase frequence of data processing.
- Depending of your application you can consider to use flash and/or fram. Erasing is slow but writing is not that slow. Erase operation usually can be carried on asynchronously.